# Integrating GCM with PHP

Tags: php, android, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I am looking to integrate google cloud messaging into my app as I want to be able to use it when I run some php. However I can't seem to find any official information on this from google, only that you can use curl. Is this the only way or is there a better way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following links are how to implement both the server and client side; both of them official documentation:

[**Server**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html)

[**Client**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

And if you are looking for how to set up the server using php:

[**link**](https://github.com/mattg888/GCM-PHP-Server-Push-Message/blob/master/GCMPushMessage.php)

Seems that using curl is very common.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Click on following link.
Register your application 
https://console.developers.google.com/

Php code you can run on local server or web server. Just change your path of server in CommonUtilities Class in SERVER_URL.
Change the SENDER_ID